# Accounting for temporal correlation in GLMM

Tags: r, time-series, logistic-regression, mixed-models, lmer

I am trying to account for autocorrelation in a GLMM. My response variable is boolean, it represents the presence and absence of a en event in the life cycle of a set of bee nests. I am trying to predict the probability of such an event with a set of numerical variables describing the state of each nest. Thefore, I used a binomial distribution in a generalized model with nest as a random effect (using glmer()). However, the events are autocorrelated, so I get a pretty horrible pattern in my residuals. If I were using a gaussian distribution in the errors without random effects, I would estimate some correlation parameters using correlation structure with gls(), but that is not gonna work in this case. I have been looking for ways to include this autocorrelation in GLMM, but I don't seem to get it right. I found that the data set can be transformed using the function ts() and diff() to allow the model to include as a predictor, previous values of the response. This works for a linear model lm(), making the residuals much nicer.

```
basket.1<-subset(basket,select=c(Nest,day,number_cells,provitioning_cells,closed_cells,
                             reopened_cells,eclosed_cells,pollen))
basket.ts<-ts(as.matrix.data.frame(basket.1),start=1,frequency=9)
m.basket.ts1<-lm(pollen~provitioning_cells+reopened_cells+closed_cells
            +eclosed_cells+day,data=diff(basket.ts,differences=2))`
```

However, neither lmer() nor glm() accept the output of those functions. The problem seems to be the the trasformation makes some values negative, and glm()does not accept negative values for a binomial model (which makes sense). I have read that it is possible to account for autocorrelations glm(), which would already be an improvement,but I cannot make it work. I also read that glmmPQL() can include correlation structures.That model runs, but it does not improve the patterns in my residuals. They still seem to be autocorrelated.

```
m.basket.glmm1<-glmmPQL(pollen~provitioning_cells+reopened_cells+closed_cells
            +eclosed_cells+day,random=~1|Nest,family=binomial,correlation=corAR1(form=~day),
            data=basket)
```

I tried different correlation structures and none of them seems to work.

Finally, I tried the dyn package, which is supposed to allow regression functions to handles time series. But once again, the function does not run with the values produced by the transformation.

```
m.bas.glm.dyn1<-dyn$glm(pollen~provitioning_cells+reopened_cells+closed_cells
                    +eclosed_cells+day,family=poisson,data = diff(basket.ts,differences=3))
```

To summarize, I need to run GLMM with temporal correlations, but I cannot find a way to do this. I would highly appreciate some help.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us a reproducible example?  In principle it shouldn't be too hard to lag values 'by hand', e.g.

```
basket.1 <- subset(basket,select=c(Nest,day,number_cells,
                             provitioning_cells,closed_cells,
                             reopened_cells,eclosed_cells,pollen))
n <- nrow(basket.1)
basket.2 <- transform(basket.1,pollen.lag1=c(pollen[2:n],NA),
                      pollen.lag2=c(pollen[3:n],rep(NA,2)))

library("lme4")
m.basket.glmm1 <- glmer(pollen~provitioning_cells+
                   reopened_cells+ closed_cells+
                    eclosed_cells+day+pollen.lag1+pollen.lag2+
                    (1|Nest),
                   family=binomial,data=basket.2)
```

Depending on the size of your data set, if `day` is numeric rather than a factor you might want `(day|Nest)` instead of `(1|Nest)` ...

Comment: What if we do not know how much to lag the values by? @benbolker

Comment: Typically you would look at a plot of the autocorrelation function of the residuals of a simple model.